# set offset to exactly of the top of the object ( set negative offset )

Tags: jquery

I have something like this

```
$('.one').hover(function(e){
  $('.roll1').show().offset({left: e.pageX, top: e.pageY});
});
```

It's working but I want to show the `.roll1` exactly top of `.one` so I tried like

```
top: '-200' // but not working tried also -200 without quote

top: e.pageY - 200 // working
```

but actually how could I set to the offset to `-200`?

Or could I not set negative offset?

Answer (score 0):

Try simply *without enclosing with quotes*

```
top: -200
```

Comment: @C-Link when I first saw your question I didn't see anything about it.  You may edited it later.  Negative offset will work. To justify I have setup a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/N2DVr/

Answer (score 0):

you should use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) if you want the div to follow the cursor smoothly,
and of course, you can use negative values with or without quotes - [example](http://jsfiddle.net/6sXds/3/)

```
$('.one').on('mousemove',function(e){
  $('.roll1').offset({left: e.pageX, top: e.pageY});
});
```

example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6sXds/2/)